# Abelianization of Category

Tags: category-theory

I know there are some natural ways to make a general category additive or even K-linear by using the free group or free vector space generated by a set and a direct sums, I also know that we may make a additive category a semi-abelian category via the Karoubi envelope, my question is wheter or not there exists a construction to take semi-abelian categories to abelian categories?

I have seen the earlier questions "[Is there abelianization of any General category?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3540901/is-there-abelianization-of-any-general-category)" but I am curious if there are others, and if possible if anybody has any refrences for such?